# Responsive design, issue on smartphone landscape

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive website that works well on desktop when I'm resizing the windows. However, when I'm testing it on "real" smartphones landscape (iphone 5, iphone 4), some font size aren't applied.

Note: the portrait version is working well

Here is an example: [WEBSITE](http://thegreatbritishbakeoff-new.todaycreative.co.uk/about-the-show/)

If you open your browser to simulate a landscape Iphone display, the font size of the text is:

font-size: 12px;
line-height: 14px;

On real model, the font-size isn't applicated

Any idea where does this issue can come from?
How can I fix it?

Cheers

Comment: >>How can I fix it?<< Post your code ...

Comment: I had a test link, any help is appreciated =)

Answer (score 2):

I think your series 1,2,3 and 4 are not taking the styles. `font-size: 11px; line-height: 13px;` which you want to be applied on it. if you inspect your code you have written these styles for p tag. however the text of your series 1,2,3 and 4 are inside the simple div. write that text inside the p tag.

Comment: Totally agree, but I'm doing some css test. I removed all the css but let only the media query and the css conditions that I want, this is working. I think, there is an enclosed tag some where

Comment: but you have written the media query for p tag and you don't have p tag on your text in series.